# Assign weights to examples in a highly imbalanced dataset

Tags: classification, sampling, dataset, unbalanced-classes, weighted-sampling

I have a highly imbalanced dataset and I'd like to train a simple ANN classifier on it. My model currently is a simple 2-layer feed-forward neural network with ReLU activation in between. After a few iterations, the model already "decides" that outputting the most seen labels is good enough and stops learning. To cope with this problem, I'd like to sample the examples in a way that each batch approximately contains the same number of examples of each class. My labels are:

```
labels = np.array([0] * 295 + [1] * 1321 + [2] * 1277 + [3] * 4477 + [4] * 457280)
```

In order to sample the rarest class the most, my current class weights are defined as follows:

```
classes = np.unique(self.labels)
counts = np.sum(self.labels[:, np.newaxis] == classes, axis=0)
frequencies = counts / counts.sum()

class_weights = 1 - frequencies
class_weights /= class_weights.sum()
```

However, because of the high imbalance, the weights of classes 0, 1, 2 and 3 are almost equal. Consequently, when I randomly sample a batch, label 4 makes up about 50% of it on average, whereas label 0 only makes up 2%.

I also tried a logarithmic weight, hoping it would discount large counts over-proportionally:

```
class_weights = np.log(frequencies)
class_weights /= class_weights.sum()
```

This weight is slightly better, but it significantly prefers label 3, which makes up about 45% of examples in a randomly sampled batch, whereas label 0 is around 5% now.

Which function could I use to assign roughly equal weights to each class, such that each sampled batch contains about 20% of examples of each class?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Since neural networks output numbers and not categories, I am confused about your claim that the network always predicts the most common category. Could you please explain how you wind up getting this?

Comment: My network outputs the softmax of the second layer as probabilities for the classes. So, I interpret `output[i]` as the probability of the ith class. To get the predictions, I simply use `np.argmax(output, axis=1)` to get the class IDs of one batch of outputs. I noticed that the networks initially predicts mostly 3 or 4, but also some other classes. But after two, three iterations the output is completely either 3 or 4. Besides, the loss doesn't change notably over hundreds of iterations.

Comment: Because of the generally low probability of the minority classes, it should not be surprising to get a low predicted probability of a minority class. It might be that the `argmax` decision rule is not particularly appropriate in this situation.